# how to get discord emoji name and id with command?

Tags: python

I am trying to program a mini bot that shows you only the name and id of the emoji through a discord command, but I have a little problem and the code I am using only shows me all the emojis that are currently on the server and only I would like to show a single emoji name and id that I select from the list of emojis

This is what is shown to me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sc0I.png

I would like only one to appear

Example: !emoji + the server emoji icon:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgomg.png

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") 
bot.remove_command("help") 
 
 
 
@bot.command()
async def emojis(ctx):
        for emoji in ctx.guild.emojis:
            await ctx.send(f"{emoji.name} {emoji.id}")
 

 
 
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")
    
 
    
bot.run('')
```

Could you help me, thank you very much!

Sorry for placing the images like this, it does not let me place them correctly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can see what you gave as input for the second one but not the first one. Can you show us that input too?

Comment: @bujian the second entry is the same as the first, I had to delete

Answer (score 0):

There is limited information from your post, but it looks like the most likely culprit is that your code is a for each loop. This part:

```
async def emojis(ctx):
        for emoji in ctx.guild.emojis:
            await ctx.send(f"{emoji.name} {emoji.id}")
```

Awaits each emoji being sent. If you just want one, you probably just want to print the first one you get back.